# RoboFrameWork Pabot :: not able to read argument file

Tags: python, robotframework, selenium2library

I am trying to achieve Parallel execution of a script in multiple browsers with the help of pabot. I have created a file(DataSet.txt) with the required arguments  here is the data set I created.

```
[Set1]
DIST_CENTER_URL=http://10.9.140.299/DC
BROWSER=Chrome
DIST_CENTER_USERNAME:demouser
DIST_CENTER_PASSWORD:login123

[Set2]
DIST_CENTER_URL=http://10.9.140.299/DC
BROWSER=firefox
DIST_CENTER_USERNAME:demouser
DIST_CENTER_PASSWORD:login123
```

and executed using this command ..    `pabot --processes 2 --resourcefile Dataset.txt ping.robot` But still my script is not picking up the parameters set. Not sure how to achieve this task? Could you please help me out here.

And also how to stop Pabot process in pycharm(i am using windows)??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pabot parallelism is on suite/file level. When executing only one file then it will not do any parallel executions.

Assuming you want all the tests executed in both browsers then what you can do is use this:

--argumentfile[INTEGER] [FILEPATH]
Run same suites with multiple argumentfile options. For example:

--argumentfile1 arg1.txt --argumentfile2 arg2.txt

Comment: Hi Mikko, thanks for your help. I am able to run my script with in cross browser way.